# How to properly uninstall the previous Excel 2010 add-in before installing the new version with windows installer?

Tags: .net, excel, deployment, vsto, windows-installer

In my setup project, I updated `Version` property, let's say from **1.0.0** to **1.0.1** (Also yes to the new product code), and then set `RemovePreviousVersions` to true. I then rebuilt the setup project.

The installation went okay but the funny thing happened when I opened up the Excel. The previous version somehow was NOT removed and still showing on the Ribbon Bar.

Apparently the installer didn't work quite right. I am not sure if I missed something or perhaps set up something wrong in the setup project.

I'd have thought changing `Version` & `RemovePreviousVersions` would be enough. Maybe I was wrong. So what else do I have to do here? Can anyone give me some pointers?

EDT:

Just 1 more thing to add here: 
I don't think I changed either Assembly version or File version when I rebuilding the installer. Which one should I update? The File one or Assembly one or perhaps both? Would it matter if I just keep the original version unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an [installation log](http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log/) to see what happens with your files. Most likely Windows Installer sees that they have the same file versions as the installed files and skips them.

You can also try increasing the file version for all your versioned files.

Comment: Thanks. I increased both assembly version and file version and it worked for me.